# How do I centre this grid of 'x' amount of squares?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm currently making a website in which 'n' number of squares is entered and then a grid of that amount of squares is displayed on the page.  The problem is that when floating the divs a small gap is left at the end of the row making the grid of squares not symmetrical.

The JavaScript is the code to set the size of each square. The PHP is the semi pseudo code for the users input of boxes and echoing of that amount of boxes.

How can I make the grid look centred? I appreciate this might be hard to grasp

```
<body>
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
        <?php
            $NumberOfBoxes = USER INPUT AMOUNT
            for ($count = 1; $count <= $NumberOfBoxes; $count++) {
                echo "<div class='box'></div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        var h = $(".container").height();
        var w = $(".container").width();
        if (w > h) {
            var NumberOfBoxes = <?php echo json_encode($NumberOfBoxes); ?>;
            var BoxSize = h * (1/Math.sqrt(NumberOfBoxes));
            $(".box").width(BoxSize);
            $(".box").css({
            "padding-bottom": BoxSize
            });
        } else {
            var NumberOfBoxes = <?php echo json_encode($NumberOfBoxes); ?>;
            var BoxSize = w * (1/Math.sqrt(NumberOfBoxes));
            $(".box").width(BoxSize);
            $(".box").css({
            "padding-bottom": BoxSize
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

### CSS

```
    html, body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}

.container {
    height: Calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}

.box-container {
    height: 89%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the css markup?

Answer (score 1):

```
.container{
    text-align:center
}
.box{
    display:inline-block
}
```

That might just do the trick for you.